# NSPanel not showing.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nspanel

My approach to this may be *all* wrong so I appreciate your patience.

I have a button in my main XIB file linked to this method in my document.m file:

```
- (IBAction)showTagModal:(id)sender {
    if (!_FileTagWindowController){
        _FileTagWindowController = [[FileTagWindowController alloc]init];
    }
    [_FileTagWindowController showWindow:self];
}
```

_FileTagWindowController is declared as a property in document.h and using breakpoints when the method is called, as far as I can tell is initializing properly, **however _windowNibName and _window remains nil**.

FileTagWindowController.h looks like this.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FileTagWindowController : NSWindowController{

}

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSArrayController *tagsArray;



- (IBAction)saveContext:(id)sender;


@end
```

FileTagWindowController.m looks like this:

```
#import "FileTagWindowController.h"

@interface FileTagWindowController ()

@end

@implementation FileTagWindowController

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Window Did Load!");
    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

- (IBAction)saveContext:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

in my FileTagWindowController.xib I have *File Owner* set to FileTagWindowController as the custom class. I have the File Owner's "window" outlet linked to the window (NSPanel). That's all that should be required correct? The NSLOG statement in WindowDidLoad never gets called. I tried using [super initWithWindowNibName] in FileTagWindowController.m but that crashes not only the app, but Xcode as well with an endless initialization loop. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks all so much.

Comment: >That's all that should be required correct?  For what!?  What is your objective?  I'm not a mind-reader.

Comment: For the window to appear when - (IBAction)showTagModal:(id)sender is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following.

```
// document.h
#import "FileTagWindowController.h"

@property (strong) filetagWindowController *FileTagWindowController;

// document.m
@synthesize filetagWindowController;

- (IBAction)showTagModal:(id)sender {
if (self.filetagWindowController == nil) {
    self.filetagWindowController = [[FileTagWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"FileTagWindowController"];
}

    [filetagWindowController showWindow:self];
    [[filetagWindowController window] setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:filetagWindowController.window];
    filetagWindowController = nil;
}
```

You may also want to call **NSWindowWillCloseNotification** to observe its state and see if filetagWindowController is closed.